# wx.ListBox selected event?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython app with three listboxes. I'd like to make it so something can only be selected in one of them at a time. I thought I could use an event when the listbox is clicked to deselect the other boxes, but there are no events listed for [wx.ListBox at wxpython.org](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListBox-class.html). Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is EVT_LISTBOX